# Comparing two samples

Tags: sample

A hospital I work for has implemented a new method of segregating patients into wards based on the complexity of their needs at the end of 2016.
We are now wondering if there is a measurable difference in nurses' workload between two wards. One of the measures we are looking at is the number of medication doses given to a patient per day.

If we randomly select 30 patients treated in 2017 from each ward and count the number of medication doses they received, will it be enough?

How should we compare these values and measure the reliability of the results?

I am guessing the number of doses patients receive is normally distributed but I can't be certain.

Many thanks

Tomasz

Comment: The number of medication doses is a discrete, non-negative number (a count), so I would not assume that to be normally distributed, but rather Poisson for example.

Comment: Do the two wards have the same number of patients? The same number of nurses?

Comment: The wards have the same number of beds and similar annual patient turnover